# Position and margin top negative values are not working on html email template

Tags: css, html, html-email, email-validation

```
<td style="padding: 0px 30px 0px 0px;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="90%" bgcolor="green">
                                <tr>
                                    <td ><div>&nbsp;</div></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="" height="30px"><div style="border-left:1px solid #00f;height:50px;margin-top:-21px;">&nbsp;</div></td>
                                    <td width="50%" height="30px"><div style="border-right:1px solid #00f;height:50px;margin-top:-21px;">&nbsp;</div></td>
                                    <td width="100%" height="30px"><div style="border-right:1px solid #00f;height:50px;margin-top:-21px;">&nbsp;</div></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table></td>
                    </tr>
                </table></td>
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question - Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 4):

Even though the question is horrible, here's the answer:

**You cannot reposition table cells by any CSS based method**. Also, you cannot control `overflow` or `height` of table cells (they **never overflow**, they will **always wrap** their full content).

**Neither can you position elements absolutely inside a table-cell**. It's just not possible.

Using a negative `margin-top` on a `div` inside a `td` will not have any effect unless the `div` has any other **preceding** element neighbors. If you had for example an `h1` before your `div` inside the `td`, you could use `margin-top: -10px;` on the div to move the `div` closer to the `h1` visually.